# Problems with virtualbox after installing Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: virtualbox

I was having problems running virtualbox (I'm new to ubuntu so I don't know much) if anyone could help that would be great! Thanks in advance.

```
DKMS: install completed.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-05-09 10:04:20 CEST; 4ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18333 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mei 09 10:04:20 Ubuntu-Omen systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
mei 09 10:04:20 Ubuntu-Omen virtualbox[18333]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
mei 09 10:04:20 Ubuntu-Omen virtualbox[18333]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
mei 09 10:04:20 Ubuntu-Omen virtualbox[18333]:    ...fail!
mei 09 10:04:20 Ubuntu-Omen systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
mei 09 10:04:20 Ubuntu-Omen systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mei 09 10:04:20 Ubuntu-Omen systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

Comment: I think the problem is `modprobe vboxdrv failed`. Do you have Secure Boot enabled? Thanks would explain it. Try disabling it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks, it worked I recently had a bios update that might have turned it back on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`modprobe vboxdrv failed` means the special drivers for VirtualBox aren't loading. This can happen for a variety of reasons but usually has to do with the Secure Boot UEFI protection.

The user confirmed that was the case after a firmware update re-enabled Secure Boot. Disabling it allowed the module to load properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is for laptop users. In my case, it is an Acer.
My VirtualBox was showing the mentioned error:

```
    > Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
    > See "systemctl status VirtualBox.service" and
    > "journalctl -xe" for details. invoke-rc.d: initscript VirtualBox,
    > action "restart" failed. ● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux
    > kernel module    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)   
...
/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I was able to fix it by disabling the secure boot on the bios. 
This option is originally greyed on the bios and it becomes available only after the supervisor password is set.

Once it is set on the security tab, the Secure Boot option is available for modifications on the Boot tab.